# selenium testNG launch 100s of urls and take screenshot. how to run in parallel?

Tags: selenium, testng

I have simple test, loads 100's of urls and take screenshoot. I would to run in parallel using testNG+selenium. Any pointers?

thanks a lot!
Raj

Comment: That is actually not a test so why do you need TestNG for that? You can do the same without any UnitTest framework

Comment: well i am using chromedriver to load the page and take screenshot so i have to use testNG.

Comment: Chromedriver and testng are completely independent things. You can easily use one without another.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the below in TestNG.xml file

**Running Parallel Test in TestNG for methods-**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name = "Parallel suite">
   <test name = "Multiple tests" parallel = "methods" thread-count = "2">
      <classes>
         <class name = "<<class_name>>" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

**Running Parallel Test in TestNG for classes-**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name = "Parallel Suite">
   <test name = "Multiple Tests" parallel = "classes" thread-count = "2">
      <classes>
         <class name = "<<class_name>>" />
         <class name = "<<class_name>>" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: above testNG parallel is for different tests. I have only one test but going in loop of urls.

Comment: Since you mention of running it in parallel, hence added these lines. If you are having only one test why would you want to run in parallel? You just want to perform loop of URLs right? Inside the test itself why don’t you loop and take the screenshot? It works

Comment: i am doing that but it takes long time as i have 100s of urls. so want to parallel.